# listagg function alternative in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to take the following data set :

```
Description                ShortDescription           Result
Actions to look for a job  job_search_action          Dont' look actively
Actions to look for a job  job_search_action          Drop off CV's
Actions to look for a job  job_search_action          Job ads
Actions to look for a job  job_search_action          N/A
```

and get this result:

```
Description                ShortDescription           Result
Actions to look for a job  job_search_action          Don't look actively, Drop 
                                                      off CV's, Job ads, N/A
```

Any help as biquery  does not have the listagg function

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`STRING_AGG()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg) for csv or [`ARRAY_AGG()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#array_agg) if you want a list-like structure (array). Then `GROUP BY` the other two columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (select 'Actions to look for a job' as Description,  'job_search_action' as ShortDescription, 'Dont\' look actively' as Result
union all
select 'Actions to look for a job' as Description,  'job_search_action' as ShortDescription, 'Drop off CV\'s' as Result
union all
select 'Actions to look for a job' as Description,  'job_search_action' as ShortDescription, 'Job ads' as Result
union all
select 'Actions to look for a job' as Description,  'job_search_action' as ShortDescription, 'N/A' as Result)

select Description, ShortDescription, string_agg(Result, ', ') from cte
group by 1,2
```

returns:

```
+-----+---------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+--+
| Row |        Description        | ShortDescription  |                       f0_                        |  |
+-----+---------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+--+
|  1  | Actions to look for a job | job_search_action | Dont' look actively, Drop off CV's, Job ads, N/A |  |
+-----+---------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+--+
```